# How to use ^#$ as record separator in awk?

Tags: awk

How do you tell awk to use a `#` character by itself in a line as record
separator?  The problem is you can't say `RS="^#$"` because `^` matches the
beginning of the file, not the beginning of a line, and `RS="#\n"` doesn't work either because it matches `#` characters that aren't at the beginning of a line.

```
$ data='#
first record, first field
first record, second field
#
second record, first field#
second record, second field
'
```

Then print the first field of each record, using `RS="#\n"`:

```
$ printf "%s" "$data" | awk '
  BEGIN { RS="#\n"; FS="\n" }
  /./ {print $1}
  '
first record, first field
second record, first field
second record, second field
```

The last line is wrong because it's not the first field but the second.  The
intended output was

```
first record, first field
second record, first field#
```

Comment: Could you please also provide an example of the output you require

Comment: so your data looks like `line one#line two#line three`?

Comment: and `RS="#"` does what?

Comment: @Skaperen no, the data looks like `#\nrecord one\n#\nrecord two` and each record consists of multiple `\n`-separated fields.

Comment: `RS='#\n'` should work afaik - although it will treat the initial `#` as terminating an empty record (i.e. all the `NR` values will be "off" by one)

Comment: Please update your Question to show the desired output.

Comment: @don_crissti yes, it should preserve the `#` I forgot about it - question edited

Comment: Where does `second record, second field` fit in your desired output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it in `awk`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$data" | 
    awk -F'\n' -v RS='(^|\n)#\n' '/./ {print $1}' 
first record, first field
second record, first field#
```

The trick is to set the record separator to *either* the beginning of the file (`^`), or a newline, followed by a `#` and another newline `\n`.

---

Comment: Note the NRs will be one-off in this case (try replacing `/./` with `NR==1`). I think the easiest solution would be to have the file/data ending - instead of starting - with a `#` on a separate line. Then `\n#\n` could be used as RS and it would work properly.

Comment: @don_crissti I just copied that from the OP. I am assuming they're using it to avoid blank lines so `NR==1` won't work if there are more blank lines further down.